# Can I run JavaScript inside Swift code?

Tags: javascript, swift, signalr

I need to include JavaScript code in Swift code to be able to call a signalR chat, is that possible? If not, can I convert it?

`sendmessage` is a button.

```
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        // some code
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            // Call the Send method on the hub.
            chat.server.send('name', 'message');
        });
    });
});
```

and the `signalr` code is:

```
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients. 
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
```

**Update #1:**

changed question a little bit so it is not confusing per @MartinR

Answer (score 84, accepted):

***Last tested with Swift 5.1***

Here is an example you can run in Playground to get you started:

```
import JavaScriptCore

let jsSource = "var testFunct = function(message) { return \"Test Message: \" + message;}"

var context = JSContext()
context?.evaluateScript(jsSource)

let testFunction = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("testFunct")
let result = testFunction?.call(withArguments: ["the message"])
```

`result` would be `Test Message: the message`.

You also can run JavaScript code within a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) calling [evaluate​Java​Script(_:​completion​Handler:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript).

*You can also run JavaScript within a [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) by calling [string​By​Evaluating​Java​Script(from:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617963-stringbyevaluatingjavascript), but note that that method has been **deprecated** and is marked as iOS 2.0–12.0.*

Comment: where i must write that code ?  can you give as a full example of that ?

Comment: Do you know how I could import the JS file into Swift?

Comment: You can do something like: `let jsSource = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path+"/jsFile.js")`

Comment: @ Daniel where i need to write these javascript code

Comment: Wherever you need to run js

Comment: @tresf would you mind sharing the final working code snippet, please?

Comment: @James everything has already been updated in the answer's code

Comment: As @Daniel has identified, the code snippet has been updated for XCode 5.1. My comment is left for historical purposes only.

Answer (score 15):

Using **JavaScriptCore framework** include JavaScript code in Swift code.

The class that you’ll be dealing the most with, is **JSContext**. This class is the actual environment (context) that executes your JavaScript code.

All values in **JSContext**, are **JSValue objects**, as the JSValue class represents the datatype of any JavaScript value. That means that if you access a JavaScript variable and a JavaScript function from Swift, both are considered to be JSValue objects.

I strongly advise you to read the official documentation regarding the [JavaScriptCore framework](https://www.appcoda.com/javascriptcore-swift/).

```
import JavaScriptCore


var jsContext = JSContext()


// Specify the path to the jssource.js file.
if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jssource", ofType: "js") {
    do {
        // Load its contents to a String variable.
        let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)

        // Add the Javascript code that currently exists in the jsSourceContents to the Javascript Runtime through the jsContext object.
        self.jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

more details refer this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/javascriptcore-swift/)